# Category page for custom-taxonomy shows 404 when using custom permalink structure

Tags: custom-taxonomy, 404-error

I'm having a small issue with category pages for a custom taxonomy when custom permalinks are used, and I was wondering if someone might be able to help out and point out where I'm going wrong.

I've created a taxonomy "Brands" for use with a custom post type (in this case, Products), using the code below place in the functions.php file of the theme. I've created a page template for the Brands page, which lists all the brands using the wp_list_categories($args) template tag, and that's all fine.

Now, if I use Wordpress' default permalink settings (where you get urls ending with ?page_id=7 and similar), clicking on any of those brands in the list, takes you to a category page which lists all the products for that brand - which is exactly the intent. If however, I set any other custom permalink structure (say /xyz/%postname%/ ), when you click on the brand name I get the 404 page instead of the category page (the same also happens when clicking view on a Brand when viewing the list within the Wordpress admin).

With the custom permalink structure, when clicking on the brand it appears to be using the correct url structure (http://www.siteroot.com/brands/brandname/) when showing the 404 page. With the default permalink setting it goes to http://www.siteroot.com/?brand=brandname, which works correctly.

I've checked various guides on making custom taxonomies, and have tried to be very careful with setting the rewrite for the taxonomy, and now I'm at a loss as to what the issue is. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );

function build_taxonomies() {  

register_taxonomy(
    'brand',
    'products',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Brands',
        'singular_name' => 'Brand',
        'search_items' => 'Search Brands',
        'popular_items' => 'Popular Brands',
        'all_items' => 'All Brands',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Brand',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Brand:',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Brand',
        'update_item' => 'Update Brand',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Brand',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Brand Name'
        ),
        'hierarchical' => true, 
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'sort' => true,
        'query_var' => true,  
        'args' => array('orderby' => 'term_order'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'brands', 'with_front' => false)
    )
);
```

}

Comment: Did you rebuild the rewrite rules by visiting the Permalinks page in Settings and saving?

Answer (score 8):

Add `flush_rewrite_rules();` after your register taxonomies. That fixed it for me.

**Edit**

Do make sure you do it on install of your plugin if you're using it on one. **It should only be run once on pug-in activation - and not on every page load**. Alternatively visit Settings > Permalinks page as this flushes the rules too.

Comment: But make sure it doesn't run on every request!

Comment: Make sure it doesn't run every request! +1000

Answer (score 2):

If you use a permalinkg structure with a front base, make sure `with_front` is `true`.

```
  'rewrite' => array(
            'slug'          => 'brands',
            'with_front'    => true
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be way off here (and this is an old question), but are you by chance using the [WP No Category Base](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/) plugin? or have you in the past on this site?

I found that when I disabled the plugin, I would get similar results to the ones you are describing.

I also had an issue with a single category listing "no posts found".

I never figured out what caused the problem, but I fixed it. [My method is posted on the WordPress.org forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-no-category-base-no-posts-found-in-one-category?replies=2).

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me was changing a value when defining the taxonomy properties.
If you set `'rewrite' => false,` then it should not give you any more problems, and you'll even be able to set the permalinks to whatever you want without giving any troubles to you custom taxonomy :)